# can i generate a text file from my iphone application

Tags: iphone

Hi 
I am creating a simple calculation based application and at end i  need to create a text file for the calculation  made in that  app.Now i want that whole result into the text file, i dont if we can create a text file through our application or not but need to create that and also if we are able to create it then can we transfer to our pc/mac .

If any tutorial is available it would be of great help .

Regards 
Mrugen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectoryPath  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.conf"];

NSString *settings = @"1.0,0.0,0.0,0,";
NSData* settingsData;
settingsData = [settings dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

if ([settingsData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES])
    NSLog(@"writeok");
```

Taken from: http://sio2interactive.forumotion.net/t347-how-to-write-a-text-file-to-iphone#1847

Comment: @ danny boy thansk for your input ,the above code will create text file right now how can i transfer the text file to my mac/pc  may be through mail , if you have any idea /suggestion please share with me .